# Error when there are plotting macros before \pgfplotsinvokeforeach

Tags: pgfplots

Why does `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` produce

> ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

when there are plotting macros before it inside a `groupplot`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 1}]
      \nextgroupplot        % When this and...
      \addplot{x^1};        % this line is commented there is no error
      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,3}{%
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot{x^#1};%
      }
   \end{groupplot}
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The arguments are expanded so `\nextgroupplot` needs a `\noexpand` just before that.

Comment: @percusse But then the output is several plots in one axis and not several plots in their own axis. Maybe I am using the wrong approach. What I want to do is to be able to do is to have different options for the first `\nextgroupplot` than the rest (in the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but this is due to the grouping inside the `foreach` loop such that `pgfplots` thinks there is a nesting going on which is not allowed. So a little bit manual ungrouped work, gives a result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 1}]
      \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x in {1,2,3}{%
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\nextgroupplot%
        \noexpand\addplot{x^\x};%
      }\temp
    }
   \end{groupplot}
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can take out the first plot. I forgot that, sorry.